# Vue.js Child Component emit data into an parent object

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I am currently trying to have a child component `$emit` data into an object of a parent, and the parent object is included in an array that is created and added to when clicking a button.

one iteration of create component button
[image: one iteration of create component button]

clicking the button twice, adds 2 more objects into the array
[image: clicking the button twice, adds 2 more objects into the array]

I do not understand how I can add numbers into amountbudgeted via props and emits while also creating new components.

New to Vue so sorry if it is not the best description

array of objects
[image: array of objects]

each object in the area has an amountbudgeted, uniqueid, remaining, input budget
[image: each object in the area has an amountbudgeted, uniqueid, remaining, input budget]

Parent Component

```
<div class="budgetItemContainer">
        <div class="budgetItemRow">
            <!--component being created via button click-->
            <div v-for="(input, index) in budgetRows" :key="index">

            <!--<component :is="$options.components.budgetItemRowContent" v-bind="budgetRows"></component>-->
                <budgetItemRowContent v-bind:="budgetRows" ></budgetItemRowContent>
            <progress data-min="0" data-max="100" data-value="20"></progress>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

export default {
name: 'budgetGroup',
components: {
    budgetItemRowContent,
    BudgetItemButton,
},
data: () => {
    return {
        budgetItemHeading: 'Housing',
        budgetRows: [
            {
                inputbudget: '',
                amountbudgeted: 0,
                remaining: 0,
                id: uniqId(),
            },
        ],
    };
},
methods: {
    //creates new budgetRow when button is clicked
    createNewContent() {
        this.budgetRows.push({inputbudget: '', amountbudgeted: 0, remaining: 0, id: uniqId() });
    },
},
}


Child Component

 <!--input that will hopefully update amoundbudgeted in parent object-->


       <div class="budgetItemRow-Column">
        <div class="budgetItemLabel">
            <input v-model="blabel" type="text" maxlength="32" placeholder="Label" class="input-Budget-Inline-Small budgetItemRow-Input">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--input that will hopefully update amoundbudgeted in parent object-->
    <div class="budgetItemRow-Column">
        <div class="amountBudgetedInputContainer">
            <input v-model.number="amount" class="amountBudgetedNumber budgetItemRow-Input input-Budget-Inline-Small" type="number" placeholder="$">
        </div>
    </div>

     export default {
    props: ['value', 'label'],
    computed: {
        amount: {
            set(newVal) {
                this.$emit('input', newVal);
            },
            get() {
                return this.value;
            },
        },
        blabel : {
            set(newLab) {
                this.$emit('labels', newLab);
            },
            get() {
                return this.label;
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just concerned with `amountBudgeted` then here's how you would lay out your code.

First, convert the component line to the following:

```
//<component :is="$options.components.budgetItemRowContent" v-bind="budgetRows"></component>
<budgetItemRowContent v-model="budgetRows[index].amountBudgeted"></budgetItemRowContent>
```

This basically just makes your code cleaner and readable. Note that I've also attached a `v-model` to the component, this is basically the same as a) passing a `value` prop and b) watching an `input` event and then updating the binding (in this case, `budgetRows[index].amountBudgeted`) with the payload of the event.

Next, change your child component to the following:

```
...
<input v-model.number="amount" ...
...

<script>
export default {
  // Name isn't 100% necessary here as it's inferred from the parent scope
  props: ['value'], //Implicitly passed from parent
  computed: {
    amount: {
      set(newVal){
        this.$emit('input', newVal)
      },
      get(){
        return this.value
      },
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

This should get you on the right track, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks your code definitely helped with my data being reset when a new item was created as well as overall emitting of input data. In your last comment you mention setting up a watcher for value. That is the next step, i am also needing the input to update the amountbudgeted in the object making it as you said a two way data binding. How would i go about doing that?

Comment: You can achieve two-way binding rather elegantly by making a settable computed rather than a copied data item.

Comment: @LandonHarvey I just updated my code with that new watcher. In hindsight, I should've added this from the get-go as it eliminates the need for any `created` logic. @Roy J Can you elaborate? What would you bind to the child component's input element? Or would you just add @input to the input?

Comment: @AndrewPeters Thank you both for helping me understand this communication better. Roy J Thanks you as well for guiding us both to learning something new.

Comment: @AndrewPeters Hey Sorry to bother. I have implemented a new input for the label feature in the child component and need a two way binding between this input as well as the amount. I understand that  v-model="budgetRows[index].amountBudgeted"  is only passing amountBudgeted as a prop and only retrieving that info as well. I need to pass multiple items in the object now and return multiple values through the input.  I have tried v-bind, and create new computed properties for the other input but have not been able to make it work. I have updated my code above to reflect this change. Thanks.